# VSCODE not connecting to salesforce org throws error, not executing any Vlocity commands

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce, vscode-extensions, vlocity

Error is as follows if I try connecting to any org or run any vlocity command.

[SalesforceConnection] [error]
Select omnistudio__Value__c from omnistudio__GeneralSettings__c where
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:34
sObject type 'omnistudio__GeneralSettings__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
[16:42:03.921] [vlocity] [error] Get Settings Error

[VlocodeService] [error] No such object with name %vlocity_namespace%__DRMatchingKey__mdt exists in this Salesforce instance